Is double excitation of nitrogen possible, and would it be able to use it as a central atom in a coordination complex?
I’m 17 and in my 2nd year of high-school (we have it a tad different here in the Czech Republic) and am interested in theoretical chemistry so that’s the explanation of the nature of my question.
So, would it be possible for nitrogen to undergo double excitation? If so, would the electron diagram look like any of the following?
$$
\begin{align}
\ce{_7N}&:~[\ce{_2He}]~\ce{(2s)^1 (2p)^2 (3s)^1 (3p)^1} \tag{1} \\ 
\ce{_7N}&:~[\ce{_2He}]~\ce{(2s)^0 (2p)^3 (3s)^2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The first one is just a shot in the dark, but my reasoning for the second is that it draws from the most stable orbital to excite it (or where to get the electron from), which would be 2s, because it’s the most closest to the core. Or is my reasoning just incorrect and it would draw from orbital 1p?
So with this out of the way, if it would be possible, would this have any real world uses?
My second question is if it would be possible to use the double-excited nitrogen as a central atom in a complex solution (coordination complex) because it would have a free orbital to accept a electron pair form a ligand?
